# How does outputing the intermidate layes in keras ,works?

Tags: keras, neural-network

from keras docs:

https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer

```
from keras.models import Model

model = ...  # create the original model

layer_name = 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

we are plugging input layer and intermediate layer to create a new model.

how does the new model know to output the intermediate layers output without info on the layers before it.

```
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This information is implicitly stored, because when you build keras tensors and layers, these are symbolic, and also store information about connections with other layers and tensors, so this information can be later used to make tricks like outputting intermediate layers.

Comment: But what about weights?
if I look inside a layer it has several variables
model.layers[2].output
model.layers[2].weights
it does not look that output layer has weights in it.

Comment: @joseph I don't understand your question